# Папка lib\ext в JRE

Tags: java

В jre есть папка lib\ext. Если я туда добавляю библиотеки, то в eclipse они должны быть видны сразу (т.е. видны как стандартные библиотеки java) или их надо добавлять через "Add External JARs..."? Если должны определяться сразу, то как сделать чтобы они подтягивались?

Comment: maven - панацея!

Comment: maven не прокатит, у меня работа с КриптоПро JCP

Answer (score 1):

Переустановил jcp, может это помогло, может в eclipse обновил jre, вообщем всё заработало